# Looking for a Module to allow presentation of data like a Microsoft Access Table

Tags: 7

A client that is currently using Microsoft Access to manage some reporting tasks would like us to extend a custom module to allow them the same (or similar) functionality on their website.

I was looking at [Data Tables](http://datatables.net/) which has a [Drupal module](https://drupal.org/project/datatables) and that would get us most of the way there however I wanted to reach out to the experts out there to see if there are any better solutions.

Their website is currently Drupal 6 but we may be rebuilding it in Drupal 7 so I will need solutions for both versions.

**EDIT** I'm interested in displaying data tabularly, but also need to have the filtering and sorting options on the columns. Data Tables has the sorting down but I don't see how it can filter.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is another module that may be helpful to you worth a shot https://drupal.org/project/tablefield

Comment: I clarified a bit on what I'm looking for in my edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think Data Tables are the answer in this case. I looked at the site more and they do have everything I need on the [extras page](http://datatables.net/extras/)

I'm not sure if the module supports add-ons so maybe I will have to update it a little.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Node Table](https://drupal.org/project/nodetable) module.

- Generates sticky headers automatically
- Supports flexible column sorting on none, one, or multiple columns
- Supports a default sort column with asc / desc option
- Supports add, delete, edit of rows and columns
- Supports drag and drop reordering of rows and columns (row reordering works only when no column sorts are enabled)

[image]

> NodeTable module is a versatile module for handling HTML tables on
>   Drupal sites. The module provides functionality for creating,
>   uploading, editing, and presenting HTML tables within nodes or as
>   nodes.

Comment: This is only for Drupal 6, and doesn't give me all of the features I'm looking for. Thanks though

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is going to be of any help, but did you consider the possibility of using:
Views: format as table and [Better exposed filters](https://drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters).

Regards

Comment: That is definitely a possibility

Answer (score 1):

Another great module for filtering and doing things to nodes (or comments or users) is [Views Bulk Operations](https://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations). You can do all the exposed filtering you want and then it lets you apply a wide variety of commands to the selected rows.

Answer (score 0):

Attempt to answer this part of the question:

> I'm interested in displaying data tabularly, but also need to have the
>   filtering and sorting options on the columns. Data Tables has the
>   sorting down but I don't see how it can filter.

1. If it's only a matter of **displaying the tabular data**, I usually just use the [datatables](https://www.drupal.org/project/datatables) module for that. It seems to work like a charm to me. Here are a few online samples to see that module at work (a rather basic views display, using the dataTables views style):

   - [AbitMORE-scm.com](http://www.abitmore-scm.com/products/reporting/builtin-reports): experiment with the search box in the upper right, eg first type "without" in it, see what happens, and then continue typing so that it becomes "without packages". Doing so you'll only get the rows displayed the contain both keywords somewhere in any of the columns (= 'and' operation), in this sample "without" in 1st column and "packages" in 2nd column.
   - [Dr.Chgman.com](http://dr.chgman.com/z-university/roadmap): similar suggestion for the search box, like "zmf z- 1.2" (pause a few secs before typing the spaces in between).

   The sorting of the tables for both samples is obvious of course (I think / hope). Just using the tiny triangles of any column you want, either ascending, or descending. Obvious, these samples are views displays. From the OP I am not sure if it is about a views display or not however. Maybe enhance the question to clarify that a bit?
2. If the question is also to **retrieve the data from an external (to Drupal) database**, and/or **if we're not talking about some view here**, then I use the [Forena module](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena) (and not the datatables module). In that case I can still use the [datatables plugin](http://datatables.net/) (not the module), because for that I just need to specify so in the "skin" that I want Forena to use for my report. Skins in Forena are used for theming reports created by forena, to add just any CSS and/or JS. If relevant for this question (the MS Access makes me doubt if yes or no), I'd be happy to enhance this answer with a few more details on forena and/or its skins.